# extjs Store proxy not writing to updateUsers.json in tutorial

Tags: html, extjs, extjs4.2

So I am following the tutorial here: http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/guide/application_architecture

I am running extjs4.2.1.

app/controller/Users.js

```
Ext.define('AM.controller.Users', {
extend: 'Ext.app.Controller',

models: ['User'],
stores: ['Users'],  
views: ['user.List','user.Edit'],

init: function() {
    this.control({
        'viewport > userlist': {
            itemdblclick: this.editUser
        },
        'useredit button[action=save]': {
            click: this.updateUser
        }
    });
},

editUser: function(grid, record) {
    var view = Ext.widget('useredit');
    view.down('form').loadRecord(record);
},

updateUser: function(button) {
    var win    = button.up('window'),
        form   = win.down('form'),
        record = form.getRecord(),
        values = form.getValues();

    record.set(values);
    win.close();
    // synchronize the store after editing the record
    this.getUsersStore().sync();
}
});
```

app/store/Users.js

```
Ext.define('AM.store.Users', {
extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
model: 'AM.model.User',
autoLoad: true,

proxy: {
    type: 'ajax',
    reader: {
        type:'json',
        root:'users'
    },
    writer: {
        type:'json',
    },
    api:{
        read: 'data/users.json',
        update: 'data/updateUsers.json'
    }
}
});
```

However, updateUsers.json NEVER gets updated on a save (.sync()).

I have check the API documentation and searched google extensively. I have found people with the same issues but no answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A json files is just a text file, so no, it doesn't get updated, because there's nothing to process it. Imagine if a page could make a request to the server and change the contents. It would be a giant security hole.

You need PHP/C#/Java/whatever to actually do something with it.

I'm curious as to why you expected that it would update, are you new to web programming?

Comment: No Im not but I AM new to extjs and the tutorial i linked above from their own documentation said it would....sooo.

Comment: Also straight from extjs documentation of the sync command: "Synchronizes the store with its proxy. This asks the proxy to batch together any new, updated and deleted records in the store, updating the store's internal representation of the records as each operation completes." which also lead me to believe that it would update the json file.

Comment: I am marking this as the answer as I have determined that its correct and the tutorial is simply mistaken.

Comment: Perhaps it could use an extra note saying that it's a static file and won't do anything, but again, if it was named `updateUsers.txt` would you also assume it would get updated?

Comment: No....what I mean is it literally says "After updating a record, the updateUsers.json file just contains {"success": true}. Since it is updated through a HTTP POST command, you may have to create an empty file to avoid receiving a 404 error." This VERY CLEARLY states that with the code in place that the file updateUsers.json WILL be updated. They are incorrect.

Comment: I'd not say that's particularly clear, especially since it's just posting to a text file and there's no way of knowing your server setup. Regardless, it never hurts to be more explicit, I'll make a change that says that it's a dummy file.